# calling json URL in fragment

Tags: android

i am calling the json file in fragment

and iam getting error in onsucces method i.e. cannot resolved method findViewById(Int).

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject, int id) {
    if (id == 10) {

        song_name = jsonObject.optString("name");
        album_name = jsonObject.optString("album");
        duration = jsonObject.optString("duration");
        TextView localTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView localTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.album_name);
        TextView localTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duration);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        localTextView1.setText(song_name);
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(album_name).into(image);
        localTextView2.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + album_name));
        localTextView3.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b></b> " + duration));

    }
}
```

Comment: for `Fragment` you need to take reference of `View` to use `findViewById()`. i.e. `view.findViewById()`

Comment: how can i use view in onSuccess() method??

Comment: @ManishaKhatke as Sandip said intialize those views in onCreateView of fragment itself then use in onSuccess.

Comment: initialize all your controls(textView,EditText etc) in `onCreateView()`

Comment: In fragment you have to use view.findViewById(), if you want to use this in onSuccess method then pass the view there and then do it or initialize it in onCreateView method. @ManishaKhatke

Comment: Have you got it? @ManishaKhatke

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView localTextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView localTextView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
        TextView localTextView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
```

Declare these four views in fragments **OnCreateView() method using view**.
and use there reference in onSuccess method. That will solve your 
cannot resolved method findViewById(Int) issue.

Comment: i allready declared the view in onCreate(), but when i am calling view in onSuccess method its geting error that "cannot resolved symbol view"

Comment: @ManishaKhatke :  Please declare in OnCreateView() where you will get fragments view reference.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant in comment is,

Declare the views as global variables and intialize in onCreateView and no need to initialize it in **onSuccess** again directly use there.

```
private TextView localTextView1;
private TextView localTextView2;
private TextView localTextView3;
private ImageView image;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
        localTextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        localTextView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
        localTextView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        //your code
        return view;
}


@Override
public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject, int id) {
    if (id == 10) {

        song_name = jsonObject.optString("name");
        album_name = jsonObject.optString("album");
        duration = jsonObject.optString("duration");

        localTextView1.setText(song_name);
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(album_name).into(image);
        localTextView2.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + album_name));
        localTextView3.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b></b> " + duration));

    }
}
```